# unlayer email template editor loadDesign in react function components

Tags: reactjs, email-templates

how it possible to set initial design for Unlayer (email template editor) in react function components?

```
import EmailEditor from "react-email-editor";
const editor = useRef()

.
.
.
.

<div className='tbcontainer'>
 <EmailEditor ref={editor} onLoad={editor.current.loadDesign(email_templates_json)} />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `useEffect` hook.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (editor.current) {
    editor.current.loadDesign(email_templates_json)
  }
}, [editor])
```

Or if you prefer, it can be done with a callback in the `onLoad` prop.

```
loadDesign = useCallback(() => {
  if (editor.current) {
    editor.current.loadDesign(email_templates_json)
  }
}, [editor])

<div className='tbcontainer'>
  <EmailEditor ref={editor} onLoad={loadDesign} />
</div>
```